# Buttons: dynamically adjust size based on the space available

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

So the requirement is, the tabs or the wizard here has to display the full name by default, and the inactive ones has to shrink based on the available space on the right side. Any idea how we can achieve this?

[image]

By default, the buttons will have width:auto. But when the no. of buttons are more and when the space on the right starts to decrease, the inactive ones has to shrink.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Hi. Can you please add some code so we could help help better?

Comment: `width : auto` or constrained

Comment: @mplungjan - I did the research but couldn't find what i was looking for. I'm looking for a clue on how to achieve this.

Comment: @RicardoRocha - I need a clue to start working on this bit of requirement.

Comment: @SagarRaj You should not need any Javascript to achieve this, you could use the [Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flexbox/info) box-model.

Comment: check your button container width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking something like that:

```js
//Number of elemnts
let count = $('li').length;

//Width of each element
let width = 100 / count;
$('li').css('width', width + '%');

//Width of elements container (ul)
let ulWidth = parseFloat($("ul").css("width"));


for (let i = 0; i< count; i++) {

  $($('li')[i]).click(function() {
  
   //Reset elements width
    $('li').css('width', 'auto');

    //Add active class to clicked element
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $($('li')[i]).addClass('active');
    
    if ( $('li').hasClass('active') ) {
    
     //Width of active element
      let activeWidth = parseFloat($("li.active").css("width"));
      let activeWidthPerc = (activeWidth * 100) / ulWidth;

      //Width of the rest of the elements
      let generalWidth = (100 - activeWidthPerc) / (count - 1);
      
      //Will only adapt when the active element is smaller than the rest of the elements
      if (activeWidthPerc < generalWidth) {
        
        $('li').css('width', width + '%');
        
      } else {
        
        $('li').css('width', generalWidth + '%'); //Set width to rest of the elements
        $('li.active').css('width', activeWidthPerc + '%'); //Set width to active element
        
      }
    
    }

  });

}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  width: 80%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

i {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: #3C8CBD;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <!--Try to add more li elements-->
      <li>
        <i class="material-icons">home</i><p>Home</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="material-icons">airplanemode_active</i><p>Plane</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="material-icons">directions_car</i><p>Car</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="material-icons">people</i><p>People</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

You can find a complete example here https://codepen.io/Nacorga/pen/MqaLGK

I hope it helps you ;)

Comment: @Nacroga - Your solution doesn't shrink the buttons when the number increases. Check my question again.

Comment: Check it now @SagarRaj. I've made some corrections.